# How to add - Data protection Entitlement for ReactNative iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile, data-protection

I want to add Data Protection entitlement for my iOS reactnative app.

I tried adding it to plist in my react native project and it dint work.

Comment: Hi! Could you add more information regarding what is not working and what you've tried to do? It will be very difficult for people to help you with your issue unless you are clear about what is your problem what steps you've taken.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just open your react native iOS project in xcode and add data protection in signing & capabilities section. Once added it will automatically reflect the added file in you react native project.